# RMI registry Remote Exception Error

Tags: java, exception, unix, garbage-collection, rmi

I am runing JBoss AS 5 on Unix. I want to start visualGC remotely from windows 7.

First, I have create an RMI Registry on port 31111 -because the RMI registery default port was busy- using the command `rmiregistry 31111 &`.

Second, I tried to start a jstatd server using the command `jstatd -p 8725 -J-Djava.security.policy=/app/home/user/jstatd.policy`.

Third, I started the Jboss Server.

Fourth, I got the process id of the server which is 9740.

Last, I returned to windows 7 and I tried to run this command `visualgc 9740@XX.XXX.X.XX:31111`.Unfortunately it returned with the following error:

`Remote Exception attaching to rmi://9740@XX.XXX.X.XX:31111`

Can you please explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer to my own question.Unfortunately, the remote JMX do not always work with JBoss.

The following table summarize the cases:

`JBoss Version -    JDK -   Works`

`4.2.3 ---- ---- 1.5 -- Yes`

`4.2.3 --------- 1.6 -- Yes`

`5.0.1 --------- 1.5 -- No`

`5.0.1 --------- 1.6 --- Yes`

`5.1 ----------- 1.5 -- No`

`5.1 ----------- 1.6 -- No`

For more information refer to [this](http://labs.consol.de/lang/de/blog/jmx4perl/jboss-remote-jmx/).

Comment: I think you have that back to front. In the table in your link, 'X' means 'Yes' and '-' means 'no'. And you shouldn't mark your own answers as correct.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you need to provide *java.rmi.server.hostname* property to jstatd.
Like so:

`jstatd -p 8725 -J-Djava.security.policy=/app/home/user/jstatd.policy -J-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=XX.XXX.X.XX`

See [RMI RemoteException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748259/rmi-remoteexception/2748878#2748878) for details.

Comment: This worked for me using an SSH tunnel to connect Windows jstat to Linux JBoss server. I used the hostname rather than the IP address, though.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at the policy file. There might be some permission issue when using VisualGC remotly . Please check out **[this](http://blogs.warwick.ac.uk/kieranshaw/entry/remote_visualgc_for/)** link.

Comment: +Santosh Thanks for your reply.  However I created a policy file already.

Comment: can you post the policy file content ?

Comment: `grant codebase "file:${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};`

Comment: Is that the only error trace you have or the error is more detailed ?

Comment: Puzzled :). Can you ping that machine ?